nginx not honoring quic/http3 streams in configuration
I'm running into a problem when sending a QUIC/HTTP3 request to my server.
My server is running nginx with QuicTLS and http3 module enabled. This is the output of my nginx -V
nginx version: NGINX-QuicTLS with ModSec/1.27.1
built by gcc 13.2.0 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4)
built with OpenSSL 3.3.0+quic 30 Jan 2024
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --build= --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-libatomic --with-pcre --without-poll_module --without-select_module --with-openssl=/src/openssl --with-openssl-opt='no-ssl3 no-ssl3-method no-weak-ssl-ciphers' --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-stream_realip_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_v3_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-debug

I'm writing a client-side program that right now is just trying to send a very basic GET request to request the / path of my server using QUIC.
The client-side library I'm using for quic is msquic and I'm using the nghttp3 library for binding the control and qpack encoding and decoding streams.
I've been unable to get a successful response from the server, every time I send a request, my server initiates a shutdown client-side and upon debugging my connection with nginx.
I'm seeing the following logs in my /var/log/nginx/error.log
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 http3 send settings
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 quic too many server uni streams:0
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [error] 800#800: *3 failed to create server stream while handling frames, client: 174.108.244.188, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 post event 0000634AA9045F68
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 quic packet done rc:-1 level:hs decr:1 pn:2 perr:0
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 quic close initiated rc:-1
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 event timer del: 6: 104359
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 quic close immediate term:1 drain:0 app error:259 "failed to create server stream"
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 quic sendto app packet max:1200 min:0
2024/10/05 00:32:49 [debug] 800#800: *3 quic frame tx app:0 CONNECTION_CLOSE_APP err:259 failed to create server stream

So it seems like my server doesn't have any remaining unidirectional streams available...
This is my nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

quic_bpf on;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    debug_connection 174.108.244.188;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    log_format quic '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http3"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log quic;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;


    http3 on;
    http3_hq off;
    http3_max_concurrent_streams 1024;
    http3_stream_buffer_size 64k;
    quic_active_connection_id_limit 128;
    quic_retry off;
    ssl_early_data on;
    quic_gso on;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

According to the http3 module documentation:
http3_max_concurrent_streams sets the maximum number of concurrent streams, but it doesn't seem to determine if its bidirectional or unidirectional streams.
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v3_module.html
I don't see any other way to set this up.
I'm looking at the source code:
https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/e24f7ccc161f1a2a759eb27263ec9af4fc7c8e96/src/event/quic/ngx_event_quic_streams.c#L83C20-L83C50
and it looks like it's comparing against this variable:
streams.server_max_streams_uni
but even If I write that in the configuration, nothing different happens, my server still gets me 0 unidirectional streams.
I'm at a loss, and I'm not sure what else I should be doing here.
